# Angular Material drag n drop CDK remove element on list

Tags: angular, angular-material

How can I remove a list item? I tried removing the item from the array associated with the list, but this breaks the list altogether.

I use Angular (with Material) 9.0

Comment: please add a stackblitz for it.

Comment: in the drop function, you has event as argument. Here you has the properties: container, previousContainer, index, previousIndex, see https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api#CdkDragDrop. You need make a `splice(previousContainer.data,previousIndex,1)` or some similar -not use the function transferArrayItem-

Comment: @Eliseo thanks, its work pretty good! I tried to use slice, but it did not work correctly, apparently due to array replacement.

Comment: @VasiliiMaslov, the idea is work with the data that comes in the "event" arg. To make the things easy, Angular give us the function transferArray. If you're curiosus, you can see in github: https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/cdk/drag-drop/drag-utils.ts. You see that it's only a function. We can use this function or not, when work with drag and drop we are working with cdkDropList, we are manage arrays (reorder, interchange two elements of two diferents arrays,...) using drag. After finish the drag, angular redraw the components with these arrays

Comment: please show code so that this is helpful for others and if you found a solution please answer the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have 2 lists. When I drag an item from the first list (sequenceOfSlides) to the second (listOfSlides), I delete it, and from the second to the first I copy it. The problem was that I removed the elements from the array associated with the list with its full replacement. With @Eliseo, I began to remove elements from the original array without changing the link to it.
Template:

```html
<div class="row" cdkDropListGroup>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div
                    id="sequenceOfSlidesElement"
                    cdkDropList
                    [cdkDropListData]="sequenceOfSlides"
                    class="example-list"
                    (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
                <div
                        class="example-box"
                        *ngFor="let item of sequenceOfSlides"
                        cdkDrag>
                    {{item.ruName}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-6">
            <div
                    id="listOfSlidesElement"
                    cdkDropList
                    [cdkDropListEnterPredicate]="noReturnPredicate"
                    [cdkDropListData]="listOfSlides"
                    class="example-list"
                    (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
                <div
                        class="example-box"
                        *ngFor="let item of listOfSlides"
                        cdkDrag>
                    {{item.ruName}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Component:

```js
 drop(event: CdkDragDrop<ISlide[]>) {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
      if (event.container.id === 'sequenceOfSlidesElement') {
        copyArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,
          event.container.data,
          event.previousIndex,
          event.currentIndex);
      } else {
        this.sequenceOfSlides.splice(event.previousIndex, 1);
      }
    }
  }
```